# Explain new Function<WebDriver, WebElement> in the FluentWait syntax

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I have this piece of code for a FluentWait.

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
       .withTimeout(30, SECONDS)
       .pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)
       .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

WebElement foo = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
     public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
       return driver.findElement(By.id("foo"));
     }
   });
```

I understand everything in the first part. Please explain how **`new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>`** works in the second part.

I have looked at the source code [(link)](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/base/Function.java) from the package ***com.google.common.base***
but couldn't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FluentWait [example in the Selenium documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html) is a bit different and simpler.

```
  Wait wait = new FluentWait(driver)
   .withTimeout(30, SECONDS)
   .pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)
   .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

  WebElement foo = wait.until(new Function() {
     public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
       return driver.findElement(By.id("foo"));
     }
   });
```

The `until()` function repeats the public `apply()` function every 5 seconds until it returns a WebElement or until the 30 seconds have passed. The findElement() function returns a NoSuchElementException when the element is not found, but this is ignored. If a WebElement is found it is placed into `foo`.

The `new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>()` is an extended version of the default Java `new Function()`.

- new Function() and Apply() explained: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html

Why these extra types have been added to your example is unclear to me. And I am not a Java Guru. They might not be necessary, but probably it makes sure you really are using a WebDriver object and not something else.

From reading the documentation of Function I think that you have to pass these Type arguments in newer versions of Java.

Java language specific details are better asked on [StackOverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/) instead of on the SQA & testing.SE

Answer (score 0):

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver) (1)
       .withTimeout(30, SECONDS) (2)
       .pollingEvery(5, SECONDS) (3)
       .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class); (4)

WebElement foo = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() { (5)
     public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) { (6)
       return driver.findElement(By.id("foo")); (7)
     }
   });
```

1. A new instance of [FluentWait](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html) is declared which incorporates your previously instantiated `driver`.
2. The FluentWait object `wait` is given a time-out of 30 seconds
3. Every 5 seconds, the `wait` will execute
4. `NoSuchElementException` will be ignored during the time-out
5. A [functional interface](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-functional-interfaces#Functions) is instantiated that takes your `driver` and returns the resulting WebElement, which is assigned to `foo`
6. the `apply` method implements the logic, taking your driver from `wait` as argument.
7. `findElement` looks for an element with an id-value of `foo` until this is found according to the settings of `wait`. If it isn't found and instead time-out is reached, execution is aborted.

Comment: The original question was how do steps 5/6/7 work. WebDriver is driving seems like an over simplification of what is happening.